# How do you use a function twice for two different equations?

Tags: c

New to coding anyways here's the question:

Write a program that uses a function to multiply two numbers and returns the result.  In your program, use the function to multiply the values 3 and 4, and then use the function again to multiply the values num1 and num2 where num1 and num2 are entered by the user.  Print the results to the screen.

Not quite sure how to use the same function for 2 different calculations. I can do everything else...

```
int multiply (int a, int b)
{
    int result;

    a = 3;
    b = 4;

    result = a * b;

    return result;
}

int main (void) {

    int n1,n2,three,four, sum, result;

    result = multiply(three,four);

    printf("result is = %d \n \n", result);

    printf("Please enter 2 int values: \n \n");
    scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);

    sum = multiply(three,four);

    three = n1;
    four = n2;

    printf("sum is = %d", sum);

    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("sum is = %d", sum);` this suggests that you want to use same function for multiplication and adding. Is that assumption correct?

Comment: No i'm using the function to multiply twice with two different set of numbers. One set of variables has pre-assigned values and the next set of variables has user assigned values.

Comment: Why are you passing uninitialized variables into a function and then immediately overwriting them with constants in the function? It seems like you don't understand the basics correctly.

Answer (score 1):

All your function needs to do is multiply two values:

```
int multiply (int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}
```

The way you use the function for two different calculations is to pass different parameters.

First you use it to multiply 3 times 4:

```
result = multiply(3, 4);
```

Then you use it to multiply two numbers entered by the user:

```
printf("Please enter 2 int values: \n \n");
scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);

result = multiply(n1 ,n2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think:

```
int multiply (int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}
```

your code has same result because you assign value into variables in function.

Comment: Yeah the values are supposed to be assigned in the function with the way the question is asked and then i'm supposed to be able to take user input for n1 and n2 and use the same function to multiply those.

Answer (score -1):

To use the same function for 2 different operations. Call it twice. Second time it takes values received from user. First time function will use build in parameters.

The static `int s` will remember that you called your function.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int multiply (int a, int b)
{
    static int s = 0;

    if(s==0)
    {
        a = 3;
        b = 4;
        s++;
        return a*b;
    }
    else
    {
       return ( a * b);
    }
}

int main (void) {

    int n1,n2,three=3,four=4, sum, result;

    result = multiply(three,four);

    printf("result is = %d \n", result);

    printf("Please enter 2 int values:\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);

    sum = multiply(n1,n2);

    printf("result is = %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
result is = 12                                                                                                                               
Please enter 2 int values:                                                                                                                   
4 4                                                                                                                                          
result is = 16
```

Comment: No this is wrong i'm not adding. I'm multiplying again with two different numbers other than the variables that are assigned an existing value. The function multiples the 2 numbers: 3 & 4 and return aresult. Then it says i'm supposed to use the same function to multiply n1 & n2 which are given values from user input.

Comment: @HibinoHareluya Is the above what you need?

Comment: Well not exactly. I can do the one you wrote but it's telling me to do the multiplication of 3 & 4 already in the function. So a = 3 and b = 4 already in that function and return result. Then I need to do another multiplication later on with n1 & n2.

Comment: @HibinoHareluya Ok, than you have to use a trick with the static variable which remembers that you called already or not.